# weblogic mandatory timeout

Tags: security, timeout, weblogic

Is there any way to force a user timeout in WebLogic application server after N hours even if the session has not been idle? That is, the user is continuously active (and thus session idle timeout doesn't kick in), but we want to force the user out, say, after 8 hours (and the user should re-login if he/she wants to continue to work).

Thanks.

-- Parag